# Copy a WPF control programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a tab control, and when the user wants to add to it, then I want to copy a couple of elements that already exist (not just reference them). Now, so far I've just hard-copied the variables I want. But I've come a cropper in the automatic sizing code- that is, the copied element noticeably lags behind the original when resizing the window. In addition, it's just infeasible to keep copying each element that I need to copy as that list grows. Is there some method I can use that will copy a WPF control? Right now, that's just a text box and a tab item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I may be miss-understanding your question, but you could create a custom UserControl, and whenever you need to add a new control, just create a new instance of that control and add it to your scene, this way you can use `DataContext`'s to help with the data binding which you can use from the control your copying:

```
MyControl newControl = new MyControl { DataContext = controlToCopy.DataContext };
myGrid.Children.Add(newControl);
```

Or similar...

or do you need it to be more dynamic than that?

Answer (score 18):

I can't quite tell what it is you're trying to do but if you want a new instance identical to an existing control instance you can use XamlWriter and XamlReader to serialize/deserialize the control:

```
MyControl copy = XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(controlInstance)) as MyControl;
```

Comment: This is a good solution but will require a lot of customization(in case you use binding, StaticResources, X:Name attributes etc.-

So you must take care of issues mentioned in these articles                                                             
Serialization Limitations of XamlWriter.Save[
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx]                                                                       

Being written by XamlWriter[
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/16/xamlwriter.aspx]

Comment: those links are dead :(